# Is there an extremely simple charting library that is JVM compatible?

Tags: java, groovy, charts

I've been using matplotlib in Python to do some rapid prototyping and data analysis. However I also have some data that's only really available via a Java API. I was thinking that if I could use Groovy + (some charting library) I could have a JVM-compatible toolkit as good as Python+matplotlib.

JFreeChart is great of course, but it's a bit complex to use in a script.

Is there a JVM-compatible charting library that has the power + simplicity of matplotlib?

Comment: Does matplotlib work with Jython?

Comment: What is the expected output? If it can be HTML or SVG, then you might be able to create the file manually.

Comment: @TomAnderson - I believe the answer is no; I think matplotlib requires the Python C bindings to work. I've heard that it might possibly work with jepp but I haven't tried this

Comment: @ThomasMueller Immediate on-screen display would be nice, but I could live with SVG or some other image file format. HTML would be more of a pain since I would have to run a browser and (depending on the solution) possibly a web server.

Answer (score 0):

JFreeChart can get pretty complex, but it can be used fairly simply too.
If you have a specific type of chart that you'd like to create, why not wrap the 'complex' parts of setting up a JFreeChart in your own java class, effectively creating a simple api for yourself ?

Comment: When I tried to do something non trivial (but *not* complex!) with `JFreeCharts` it could not be done without multiple source code changes/bug fixes. It was along the lines of plotting multiple time series on a single chart: a run-of-the-mill task for `matplotlib` and friends. This was confirmed by a couple of committers to the project. I ended up scrapping that approach and writing `JavaFX` code. *That* one could do it .. but at a cost of a few hours of effort.  IMO charting on the JVM is still  an unsolved problem/.